# adding .php via rewrite rule makes custom 404 inaccessible

Tags: .htaccess

This is my .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
ErrorDocument 500 /500.php

php_flag log_errors on
php_value error_log "/www/htdocs/w0123456/errlog/errorlog.txt"

php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
php_flag register_globals off

<IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
    Options -Indexes
</IfModule>

CheckSpelling off

SetOutputFilter DEFLATE

DirectorySlash Off

Options -MultiViews

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.(html?|php)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^search$ search.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^concat$ concat.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap$ sitemap.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

It works fine, but when I type a url that doesnt exist, I get a 500 server error instead of seeing the custom 404.php page.

What do I need to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `-f` check in your php extension rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCOnd %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```